# Encountering a weird key error, is this something to do with json or my statements?

Tags: python, for-loop, discord.py

Im writing a discord.py bot and this is the warns command, it gets warns logged by the warn cmd!
Why do I get a key error? My JSON:

```
{"777618366894571530": {"1": "ROMO charged by ROMO#6714 for demo"}}
```

My script to get the warns:

```
if str(guildid) in warns:
    for value in warns.items():
        
        warnval = warns[str(guildid)][value]
        if user in warnval:
            embed.add_field(name=f"``Warn {value}``", value=f"{warnval}", inline=True)
        
else:
  await ctx.send("Guild has no warns!")
```

My full warns cmd to get warns from the json:

```
  @command()
  @cooldown(9, 20, BucketType.user)
  async def warns(self, ctx, user : discord.Member):
    guild = user.guild
    guildid = user.guild.id
    userid = user.id
    print("LOADING")
    warns = {}
    guildid = ctx.guild.id
    placing = (len(warns)+1)
    with open("./warns.json","r") as f:
      warns = json.load(f)

    embed = discord.Embed(title=f"Warns", description= f"Warns for user {user}", color=0x00ff00)

    
    if str(guildid) in warns:
      for value in warns.items():
        
        warnval = warns[str(guildid)][value]
        if user in warnval:
          embed.add_field(name=f"``Warn {value}``", value=f"{warnval}", inline=True)
        
    else:
      await ctx.send("Guild has no warns!")
    

    embed.set_footer(text=f"These are {user.display_name}'s warns.")
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: Help as usual would be much appreciated :)

Comment: There is no JSON in your code. You are working with a `dict`. JSON is a text-based serialization format. In any case, you need to provide a [mcve]. If you are getting an error, post the *full error message including the stack trace*

Comment: But why do you assume `warns[str(guildid)][value]` will be there?

Comment: Forgot to add try: except: around the ```warns[str(guildid)][value]```

Comment: Is `warns` the dictionary at the top?

Comment: it makes no difference though, because ik the value does exist

Comment: yes warns is the dictionary

Comment: @RomulusHill what? Did you mean to write "i know the value does exist"

Comment: I will quickly add a new part to my question containing the entire warns cmd

Comment: @RomulusHill you don't need to add the entire warns command, you want to add a [mcve[

Comment: `value` is a dictionary, you can't use it as the key of a dictionary.

Comment: Ok, I have put in the entire warns cmd

Comment: hopefully you can all see it now

Comment: @Barmar well, a `tuple` with a `dict` in it.

Comment: @RomulusHill you **still** have not added a [mcve]. EDIT also, don't tell us to ignore incorrect indentation, *correct the formatting*

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Right, I was thinking of `warns.values()`. But still, `warns[str(guildid)][value]` makes no sense. What are you actually trying to do in this loop?

Comment: @Barmar yeah, it absolutely makes no sense.

Comment: Honestly i am attempting to learn discord.py and python at the same time, so im not very good at this, but im not using tutorials so im learning as I go so its quite messy, but, I have assigned a string to the dictionary I think, by saying this in the warn cmd: ```warns[str(guildid)][identifier] = finalreason``` Finalreason is the reason and contains user data

Comment: and now I want to grab the string back from the whole thing

Comment: I don't know what else tell you.`value` is the tuple `(777618366894571530", {"1": "ROMO charged by ROMO#6714 for demo"})`, which is not in the dict ` {"1": "ROMO charged by ROMO#6714 for demo"}`

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```
found_warning = False
if str(guildid) in warns:
    for key, warnval in warns[str(guildid)].items():
        if user.name in warnval:
            embed.add_field(name=f"``Warn {key}``", value=f"{warnval}", inline=True)
            found_warning = True
if not found_warning:
    await ctx.send("Guild has no warns!")
```

`items()` returns tuples containing the dictionary keys and values. You only want to search for the user in the value. You don't need to index the dictionary again, since it returns the values.

Use the `found_warning` variable to tell whether it found the user in any of the warnings.

Comment: Honestly idk if thats what I want, ill go and see how it all works then ill tick your answer if it works! Tysm for helping guys!

Comment: Undefined name value in the embed and undefined name warnval Both claim to be undefined in the embed

Comment: ```Command raised an exception: TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not Member```  Is this error a result of the warn cmd not setting the value properly so it works with the warns cmd?

Comment: Since `user` is a `discord.Member` object, you need to use `user.name` to get the username.

Comment: Ahh ok, ill try it now